# ngMessages: Validating Email with AngularJS

Tags: angularjs, validation, ng-messages

I would simply want to vaildate the email field with AngularJS and ngMessages.

I want 3 validation rules:

- Required
- Maxlength
- Email

I want to display the errors message + error border of `Required` and `Maxlength` when the validation fails on either one of those terms and the input field is **dirty**.

In the meantime, I want to display the error message + error border of `Email` when the validation fails with it and the input field is **touched** only. If it's dirty I don't want to disply the email error message, becuase that would be annoying for the end user.

Here is my code:

```
<input 
    type="email" 
    placeholder="Email" 
    name="emailField" 
    ng-model="emailField" 
    ng-class="{'error-border': (form.emailField.$dirty && form.emailField.$error && !form.emailField.$error.email)}"
    required
    ng-maxlength="10"
>
<div class="form-error" ng-messages="form.emailField.$dirty && form.emailField.$error && !form.emailField.$error.email">
    <p ng-message="required" class="ferror">
        <i class="delete"></i>
        Email is required.
    </p>
    <p ng-message="maxlength" class="ferror">
        <i class="delete"></i>
        Email is too long.
    </p>
    <p ng-message="email" class="ferror">
        <i class="delete"></i>
        Email is invalid.
    </p>
</div>
```

It's not working however.

Can anyone help me with this?

Comment: Please define "it's not working". What happens? When doing what?

Comment: @JBNizet Actually, it's either not displaying the errors correctly or displaying the email errors when the input is only dirty.

Comment: The second requirement contradicts to the first one when, if you enter "sssssssssss" then both email and maxlength are true but and the field is dirty. So should the border be rendered?

Comment: @ Ah I meant when either of those is throwing an error. I simply want to display the Email message + border when it's touched and there's an email error.